my gestures seem off, and my raycast is not detecting planes correctly
import ARKit
import RealityKit
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation
import Combine

class CustomARView: ARView, ARSessionDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    private var utility: Utility
    private var currentEntity: Entity?

    required init(frame frameRect: CGRect, utility: Utility) {
        self.utility = utility
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        setupARView()
        subscribeToActionStream()
        setupLocationManager()
    }

    required init(frame frameRect: CGRect) {
        self.utility = .sdge // Default value or you can handle it differently
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        self.automaticallyConfigureSession = false
        setupARView()
        subscribeToActionStream()
        setupLocationManager()
    }

    @objc required dynamic init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func setupARView() {
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical]
        configuration.environmentTexturing = .automatic
        session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
        session.delegate = self
        print("AR session started with configuration: \(configuration)")
        
        let debugOptions: ARView.DebugOptions = [.showFeaturePoints, .showWorldOrigin, .showAnchorOrigins, .showAnchorGeometry]
        self.debugOptions = debugOptions
        
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
        addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        
        let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePinch(_:)))
        addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
        
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan(_:)))
        addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

        let rotationGesture = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleRotation(_:)))
        addGestureRecognizer(rotationGesture)
    }

    private func setupLocationManager() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        print("Location manager started.")
    }

    @objc private func handleTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = gesture.location(in: self)
        print("Tap detected at location: \(location)")
        
        // Check if the tap hit an existing entity
        let hitTestResults = hitTest(location, query: .all)
        if let firstHit = hitTestResults.first(where: { $0.entity is ModelEntity }) {
            // If it hit, remove the entity
            if let entity = firstHit.entity as? ModelEntity {
                print("Existing entity hit: \(entity.name), removing it.")
                entity.removeFromParent()
                currentEntity = nil
            }
        } else {
            // If it didn't hit, place a new entity
            if let raycastResult = raycast(from: location, allowing: .existingPlaneGeometry, alignment: .horizontal).first {
                print("Raycast succeeded, placing model.")
                placeModel(at: raycastResult.worldTransform)
            } else {
                print("Raycast failed. No surfaces detected.")
            }
        }
    }

    @objc private func handlePinch(_ gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let entity = currentEntity else {
            print("No current entity to scale.")
            return
        }
        let scale = Float(gesture.scale)
        entity.scale *= SIMD3<Float>(repeating: scale)
        gesture.scale = 1.0
        print("Scaled entity: \(entity.name) to scale: \(entity.scale)")
    }

    @objc private func handlePan(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let entity = currentEntity else {
            print("No current entity to move.")
            return
        }
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: self)
        let xTranslation = Float(translation.x / frame.width)
        let yTranslation = Float(translation.y / frame.height)
        
        entity.position.x += xTranslation
        entity.position.z += yTranslation
        gesture.setTranslation(.zero, in: self)
        print("Moved entity: \(entity.name) to position: \(entity.position)")
    }
    
    @objc private func handleRotation(_ gesture: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let entity = currentEntity else {
            print("No current entity to rotate.")
            return
        }
        let rotation = Float(gesture.rotation)
        entity.transform.rotation *= simd_quatf(angle: rotation, axis: SIMD3<Float>(0, 1, 0))
        gesture.rotation = 0
        print("Rotated entity: \(entity.name) to rotation: \(entity.transform.rotation)")
    }
    
    private func placeModel(at transform: simd_float4x4, modelName: String? = nil) {
        let modelToPlace = modelName ?? {
            switch utility {
            case .sdge:
                return "Cell.256"
            case .sce:
                return "Cell.1024"
            case .pge:
                return "Cell.2048"
            }
        }()
        
        guard let modelEntity = try? Entity.load(named: modelToPlace) else {
            print("Error loading USDZ model: \(modelToPlace)")
            return
        }

        // Correct the orientation and scaling
        var transform = transform
        // Rotate model counterclockwise by 90 degrees around the z-axis
        let rotation = simd_float4x4(SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(.pi / 2, 0, 0, 1)) // Rotate around z-axis
        transform = simd_mul(transform, rotation)
        
        // Set initial scale to ensure it's not too zoomed in
        modelEntity.scale = SIMD3<Float>(repeating: 0.01) // Adjust scale as needed

        let anchor = AnchorEntity(world: transform)
        anchor.addChild(modelEntity)
        scene.addAnchor(anchor)
        currentEntity = modelEntity
        print("Placed model: \(modelToPlace) at transform: \(transform)")
    }

    private func subscribeToActionStream() {
        ARManager.shared.actionStream
            .sink { [weak self] action in
                print("Received AR action: \(action)")
                switch action {
                case .removeAllAnchors:
                    self?.scene.anchors.removeAll()
                    print("All anchors removed.")
                case .addARObject1:
                    self?.addARObject(named: "Cell.256")
                case .addARObject2:
                    self?.addARObject(named: "Cell.1024")
                case .addARObject3:
                    self?.addARObject(named: "Cell.2048")
                }
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    private func addARObject(named modelName: String) {
        if let cameraTransform = session.currentFrame?.camera.transform {
            let distance: Float = 1.0 // 1 meter in front of the camera
            var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4
            translation.columns.3.z = -distance
            let finalTransform = simd_mul(cameraTransform, translation)
            placeModel(at: finalTransform, modelName: modelName)
            print("Added AR object: \(modelName) at distance: \(distance) meters in front of camera.")
        } else {
            print("Error: Unable to get camera transform.")
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else {
            print("Error: No location data available.")
            return
        }
        print("Location updated: \(location)")
        // Handle location updates
    }
}

extension Entity {
    func findEntity<T: Entity>(ofType type: T.Type) -> T? {
        if let match = self as? T {
            return match
        }
        for child in children {
            if let match = child.findEntity(ofType: type) {
                return match
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

i have been manipulating the objc functions to handle rotation and pan but sliding finger up and down just makes it grow while pinching and twisting it still doesn't rotate the object.  it moves left and right fine, and it grows and shrinks fine but can't get it to rotate or recognize the plane/ surface it should sit on.
UPDATE: looks like i can rotate it horizontally just not the other way, which i gues i can't rotate around the z axis? and the sliding up and down still just makes it grow and shrink.

getting closer, found in my panHandle function i was setting entity.position.z += yTranslation when first part should not be z but y ! ugh.
